# Accessing Raspbian Filesystem on SD-Card via USB-Connection from Windows

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible to access the filesystem directly via USB when i connect it to my Windows PC ?
I don't want to ssh on the system, i  want to mount it inside the Windows operating system, so that i can directly write to it without establishing a ssh connection for example.

Any Ideas how to do this ? Or isn't this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to simply accessing the file system you can always use some piece of software that will allow you to access linuxish file systems, so you can just plug in the SD card to your Windows machine (A quick google search: http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

However, if you want your Raspberry running during those actions, you could use some sort of usb to serial cable (like this one:    http://www.adafruit.com/products/954), but you will still need to use Putty or some similar software for the serial connection. On the bright side, connecting your pi that way means it will no longer need an external power supply. Just on a side note, what are your concerns about the ssh connection?